# Huge multi nested form failing with "An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

We created a multi-nested form in Rails 5, the forms having image objects, many fields.

after having 200+ items in a single form and trying to save the form, we started getting those errors.

> An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details.

there is nothing logged in the error logs, nginx access logs seems like it got the request, but Puma really didnt like the huge request.

any idea how can we fix this? we need the huge request.

Comment: Are you sure it's server specific (and not Rails or Rack)? did you try testing if the issue is server related, perhaps using iodine or passenger? Also, some servers (i.e. iodine) have a maximum body (upload) size that you can set to whatever value you need (this is important for security reasons, you don't want that 2Gb request hogging your resources)...

Comment: @Myst thanks buddy, your comment "rails or Rack" related problem helped me find the cause of the problem.

Comment: I'm happy I could help :-) Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so I ended up taking a copy of the live server database and installing it locally, then I took a look at the console which was logging:

> Too many open files - Maximum file multiparts in content reached

googling around for a bit knowing that the multi nested form of mine is the cause of the problem, I decided to increase the rack multi part limit to 512 like so in my `config.rb`

> Rack::Utils.multipart_part_limit = 512

saved the file, uploaded to the server and restarted it. everything works perfectly now, thanks everyone.